# Phonegap / Cordova Change volume of individual sound?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, cordova

Using Phonegap / Cordova 2.2 with its media API to load loops for playback in my App. 
(http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media)

Working fine, but I would like to be able the change the relative levels of each sound programmatically. Does anyone know if this is possible?

The only option I can see is avoiding the Native Phonegap solution and using Web Audio /html5 but that would limit the apps to ios6 devices only.

PS. I'm also aware of the volume slider plugin for IOS, but need a solution that only affects single sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cordova 2.0 onwards (as I found out) there is a way to change the sound volume programmatically. Undocumented but goes something like this (where x = 0 through to 1)

```
MySound.setVolume(x);
```

Note that it only effects the volume of a sound before it has started to play. It wont change the volume of a sound already playing ( I have submitted a feature request)

Comment: did your feature request ever get implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the Low Latency Audio Plugin. Some folks have down pull requests against it to support setting the volume. Check the comments of:

http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap/