# Phonegap iOS volume control

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

iPhone has 2 options for volumecontrol:

- Device/application sound
- Mediaplayer sound

The default is device sound. When you press the volume down control the device sound will decrease. But when you play music the sound will change in the mediaplayer sound.

How can I change the default volumecontrol in PhoneGap, so when you press volumedown or up the music volume will change and not the device volume.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure its possible. As I thought it was managed by the OS ??

You can change the level of the sounds played through phonegap programmatically though. 
So if you can create a couple of buttons in your app you can adjust it.

See the last reply here [Phonegap / Cordova Change volume of individual sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436540/phonegap-cordova-change-volume-of-individual-sound)